# Is the "wing area" of a biplane the projected area or the total area?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, terminology, biplane

When you specify the wing area of a biplane, do you specify the planform area (the projected area) or do you specify the effective area of both the wings?

Comment: I could have sworn we had this exact question, or a very similar one about interference and effective wing area, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mixture of both: You add the projected area of both wings, measured separately, without overlap.

The effective (wetted) area is used for friction drag calculations only.